# Css, image and js not working in .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my code is  below , and my code is not able to fetch all css, js and images which is located in diffrent folders

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [NC] [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+product\.php\.css\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ product/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^product/([^/.]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z\s0-9-]+)/?$ /product.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What is the browser looking for? You can check the console to see what files it is trying to fetch. Perhaps it is just a relative-path issue.

Answer (score 0):

> `RewriteRule ^ product/%1? [R=301,L]`

This is almost certainly caused by using relative paths in your HTML to your CSS, JS and images. You are redirecting the request to a "virtual" subdirectory, so any relative paths in your HTML are going to be relative to this subdirectory, not the document root, as is probably required.

You need to either set a `base` tag in the `head` section to state the URL that all relative URLs are *relative* to. Or change your URLs to be root-relative (starting with a slash) or absolute. For example:

```
<base href="http://example.com/product.php">
```

See also my answer to a similar question on the Pro Webmasters stack:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that, your relative URIs have their base changed. Originally, the base is `/` when the page is `/product.php`, and the browser properly fills in relative links with the `/` base. But when the browser goes to a page like `/product/` the base suddenly becomes `/product/` and it tries to append that in front of all relative URLs and thus none of them load.

You can either make your links absolute, or change the URI base in the header of your pages (inbetween the `<head> </head>` tags):

```
<base href="/">
```